# support arm64 aarch64 arm armv7hl libswt-gtk-4763.so in smartgit

Tags: swt, arm64, smartgit

I want to add arm64 (aarch64bit) or arm (armv7hl) support to smartgit.

When i open smartgit it say:
Could not load SWT library. Reasons:
`Can't load library: swt.tmp/libswt-gtk-4763.so`

What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Download [eclipse-swt-4.7.3a-5.fc28.aarch64.rpm](https://rpmfind.net/linux/fedora/linux/updates/28/Everything/aarch64/Packages/e/eclipse-swt-4.7.3a-5.fc28.aarch64.rpm)
found in this [search](https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libswt-gtk-4763.so()(64bit))

extract it.
at usr/lib/java/ you will find: swt.jar.
rename it to `org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64.jar`
copy and replace at `smartgit/lib/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64.jar`
then it will work on aarch64 machine :)

The same can be done for arm (armv7hl) with this [file](http://rpmfind.net/linux/fedora/linux/updates/28/Everything/armhfp/Packages/e/eclipse-swt-4.7.3a-5.fc28.armv7hl.rpm) in this [location](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libswt-gtk-4763.so):